# How to stop IDLE defaulting to C:\Python33 folder when saving

Tags: python, python-idle, customising

I'm developing a customised version of Python 3.7 for my school, mostly because they have the C drive blocked and IDLE's default save location is C:\Python33. I've got the source code because I'm also changing a couple icons and stuff, so how would I go about changing the default save location? I checked `config.py` in the `idlelib` folder but that only has references to `<<save-window>>` and that's just a keybinding to `<Control-s>`. Any help?

Comment: 3.7? Any particular reason you're picking a version that's still in pre-alpha? It's not anywhere near ready for release.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to configure python to default the save location to anything other than `C:\` because you cannot access it.

This can be done by either moving/copying the `Python3.3` directory elsewhere (worked for me) thus changing the path variable which opens the saving dialog in the current directory or editing the `IOBinding` class which can be looked up here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/idlelib/iomenu.py#L112

Let me know what worked for you.

Comment: Trying it now. Will let you know.

Comment: Checking through that `iomenu` class and I can't see any variable or setting to edit that changes the default save location.

Comment: have you tried moving first ? also I see a `dirname` attribute in `IObinding` class, maybe also try that